# React Native child component not rendering on onPress event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render the child component on `onPress`event, the `console.log` works fine but components in the return function doesn't works.

> Parent component:

```
 onPress = (img,title,content) => {
  this.setState({
  show:true,
  img:img,
  title:title,
  content:content
})
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList 
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.onPress(item.urlToImage,item.title,item.content)}
          >
          <View style={styles.picsCont}>
          <Image style={styles.pics} source={{uri: item.urlToImage}}/>
          <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: '700', paddingTop:10}}>
          {item.title}
          </Text>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
        />
        {this.state.show ? 
        <NewsView
         img={this.state.img}
         title={this.state.title}
         content={this.state.content}
         /> :
        null
      }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> Child Component:

```
export default class NewsView extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.img)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.picsCont} source={{uri:this.props.img}} />
      <Text style={styles.news}>{this.props.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.news}>{this.props.content}</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help...!

Comment: Probably you just copy-pasted wrongly, but the closing bracket `}` of the onPress() method is missing and you have an extra one at the end of the render. This way render() is inside onPress()

Answer (score 0):

It might be the styles. If your child component has `position:'absolute'`, it´s probably under your parent component, you can try to put on your child component view `zIndex:10`